# how to remember input data in the forms even after refresh page?

Tags: php

what to do in order to make the form remember the previous input or the current input of the user even after he/she refreshed the page ?

should I do ,

```
            <div class="row">
             <label>Contact Messenger </label>
             <input type="text" name="messenger" id="messenger" size="50" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['messenger']; ?>"/>
            </div>
```

or

```
            <div class="row">
             <label>Contact Messenger </label>
             <input type="text" name="messenger" id="messenger" size="50" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $_POST['messenger']; ?>"/>
            </div>
```

or

there's a trick to do it ?..how ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

on the page where your form is submitting do something like this

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
    $_SESSION['data_another'] = $_POST['data_another'];
```

and than you can access those session variables any where like this

```
    session_start(); // this should be at the top of the page before any html load
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data'];?>"/>
```

refresh your page on success call like this

```
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "yourfile.php",
           data: 'data='+ data,
           success: function(){
               location.reload();
           }
       });
```

Comment: if you are submitting your form via ajax than it will require a page refresh for the session variables to work.

Comment: yes, the form is submitted via ajax..can you give a sample of page refresh via ajax submission ?

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue at one of my project so I wrote some js to handle this using cookies.
First I found two simple functions to set and get cookies values:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```

Than I wrote two other functions to set and get input values:

```
function saveValue(input) {
    var name = input.attr('name');
    var value = input.val();
    setCookie(name,value);
}

function getValue(input) {
    var name = input.attr('name');
    var value = getCookie(name);
    if(value != null && value != "" ) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And using jQuery I save user's input value to session cookie

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var value = getValue($(this));
    $(this).val(value);
}).on('blur', function(){
    if($(this).val() != '' ) {
        saveValue($(this));
    }
});
```

I hope it'll help ;)

Answer (score 2):

That quite depends on where the data in the fields is coming from.
If your scenario is that you are presenting a blank form, the user enters some data and then without submitting it, refreshes the page, there is nothing you can do. That's up for the browser to handle.

You might be able to do some very weird JavaScript hacking there, but I would not suggest that.

On the other hand, if your data is coming from a previous page or something like that, that's a different story. But then you need to tell us where the data is coming from, so I can give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: it's a blank form, when the user is not logged-in or register and he hit the submit button, a jquery modal pops-up and from there, he can register, once he registered from the modal, he gets logged-in automatically, the page automatically refreshes and shows his username.. and should be able to return back to the form that he left behind the jquery modal..how to do that ? because when i refresh the page, the input data is gone

Comment: To achieve that you will have to send all the data form the original form together with your login form. Then the login script can save that in a session variable and you can fill the form with that data when  you generate it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, filling out form fields and clicking refresh, then there is no direct way, as the data isn't submitted.  That sort of behavior is up to the browser.

The only thing you could do is post the data via AJAX back to your server as the fields change.  Your PHP script receiving the data would set some session variables.  When the form loads, you would set their default values to the appropriate session values.

Rarely though is there a need for this kind of behavior.  There will be many requests sent back and forth to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Session is a good way to store and remember data but why complicate things? Consider if the form has many fields, developer has to store lots of values in session. Why not simply print or echo.

Example:

Form is submitted with input ssName and hidden field ssAct with value of send

Get the ssName and ssAct on form submit

```
$ssAct=$_REQUEST["ssAct"];
$ssName=$_REQUEST["ssName"];
```

and the form

```
<input type="text" name="ssName" value="<?php if($ssAct=='send' && $ssName!='') { echo "$ssName"; } ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ssAct" value="send">
```

On submit name will be echoed if it was submitted and was not empty.

Comment: The simple php echo method that I have described will work even after refresh (not Ctrl+refresh). Because the form will be posted again with the values. Its not perfect solution, but its simple work around.

Comment: I never use sessions to store form values. They are already stored in your form fields, either the visible ones or the hidden ones that you may make to hold, for example, the previous value of a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

None of your suggestions will help you "remember" data after a refresh (action that not send data to the server). What you need is to grab data via javascript (maybe with onkeyup events type) and  grab it using cookies. With jquery is very easy.

Comment: @sasori: Sorry, no time to a sample, I would like it but I can't. [the cookie is easy to use with this plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

There are some main issues to check in order to get the data appear after refresh or any event handler:

1) Be aware of the  signature. it must contain the method="post" attribute as follows:

```
    <form method="post"/>
```

else the using of the  $_POST['messenger'] will not work.

The default value of the method attribute in the form is get.

```
    <form>  equals to  <form method="get">
```

2) Many programmers mix between the attributes **id** vs **name**.
Be aware of using the correct attribute. The $_POST associative array is using the **name** to get data from it. That is why the next example **will not work** correctly:

```
    <input type="text" id="data" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "" )?/>"
```

To get it work right you must add the attribute name="data" as follows:

```
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "" )?/>"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could also do without session like the below code:

```
<input type="text" name="Fname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Fname'])){ echo $_POST['Fname']; } ?>" /><br/>
```

This will keep the typed data inside the input box!

Answer (score 0):

after posting your details to session, write like this in value

> `<?php print $_SESSION['messenger'] ?>`

if you are writing both php and HTML in same file then you can do like this

> `<?php print $messenger] ?>`

Answer (score -1):

try the attribute `autocomplete`, maybe it will work on some browsers...

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" />
```

You can use autocomplete for a `form` too.