# Maintain checked state of dynamically generated checkboxlist on auto refresh asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view called **one.cshtml** which has another view inside it called **two.cshtml**. There is 
a **automatic refresh code on one.cshtml** page which should refresh only the **two.cshtml** section of the page
THis is working as expected, every 5 seconds there is auto refresh and only two.cshtml gets called.

This is how two.cshtml is called from one.cshtml

```
<div id="PartialViewTwo">
    @Html.Action("two")
</div>
```

The javascript file has the code for auto refresh which calls the "two.cshtml" to be loaded

```
if (!isNaN(reload_interval) && reload_interval > 0) {
     timer = setInterval(function () **{ $('#PartialViewTwo').load("two");** }, reload_interval);
 }
```

**Problem** : If the user has selected 'n' number of checkboxes,when the auto refresh happens, the selections(checkboxes checked) state vanishes.**How can I maintain the checked state of the checkboxes during auto refresh?**

The checkboxes are group of checkboxes or checkboxlists with the same name which are generated dynamically.

I am using asp.net MVC 4 and this is my first project in MVC. I am used to viewstate in webforms, but here there is nothing like that.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using autorefresh? if it's supposed to get new data from server, then you don't need client state. in the other hand, if you need states that are selected in client, then why autorefresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some browsers will automatically cache form inputs. This behaviour can be triggered by the "autocomplete" attribute. However, I think what you will want to do for your case is to programatically save the state of the form before auto-refresh is called.

Comment: this answer has a guide showing how this could be done with session data http://stackoverflow.com/a/7014341/1772288

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I was thinking of saving the state when the checkbox checked state changes using jquery. What are best options to store this? For ex session, html5 storage, cookies etc. My application need to be crossbrowser, cross platform comaptible. What is the best approach for this scenario?