# How to keep form data even after submiting not to dispear

Tags: php, html

In this

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1" />
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="print"  name="print"/>
</form>
```

After I submit the form, the page refreshes and the data inside the input texts gets blank

Is it possible to keep the data even after submit?

Regards.

Comment: Heared of ajax...:-) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Same topic with a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014146/how-to-remember-input-data-in-the-forms-even-after-refresh-page

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 Probably no one ever heard of someone that heared of ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to echo, what ever is the variable named for your input.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1" value="<?php echo $_POST['tex1'];?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="print"  name="print"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use ajax for submitting the form.

Or use following

```
<form method="POST" action=""><input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1" value="<?php (isset($_POST['text1]))? echo $_POST['text1] : '';" /><input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/><input type="submit" value="print"  name="print"/></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

With php  for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1" value="<?php echo $_POST['tex1']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="print"  name="print"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Add a check if the post is set or it will echo a undefined variable if there is no post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling the post on the same page you could just do like this on the fields where you want the posted value to be shown:

```
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search" <?php if( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ){ echo "value=\"". $_POST['search'] ."\"; } ?>/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tex1'])) echo $_POST['tex1'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="print"  name="print"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bascially http is statelessprotocol , hence you need to save the data some where

The simplest way in this case would be  to use a conditional operator

```
   <input type="text" class="field small-field" name="tex1"  value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['search'] || $_POST['search'] )?$_POST['tex1']:''); ?>" />
```