# Refresh the page without resetting search query after changed are made

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a search page where the search fetches data from a SQL database. There are different functions for the search results like edit and delete. My problem is, when I edit or delete a search result, the page refreshes and loads only the search bar. I want the page to reload with the results of the previous search, but with the edits/deletes that was made. Is there a general way of doing this? I searched online and found that `mysqli_close($link);` is the cause for this. That means closing the connection and reopening. I commented out this line, but still the page refreshes and loads only the search bar.

I will post the code of a function and the form that calls it. Ignore the missing code for the `gtype`. There is a lot of code to select the type. I am not using SESSIONS and don't intend to.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    $gid = $_POST['gid'];
    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    $gtype = $_POST['gtype'];

    $update = " UPDATE galleries_info SET 
    Gallery_Name='$gname', Gallery_Type_Id='$gtype' WHERE Gallery_Id='$gid'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $update);
    echo "Gallery updated";

    //mysqli_close($link);
}
?>php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){ ?>

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username,$password ,$db );
$search_result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
<!-- populate table from mysql database -->
<?php 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
<form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h3>Gallery Info</h3>
  Gallery ID: <input type="text" name="gid" readonly value="<?php echo $row['Gallery_Id']; ?>"  /><br><br>
  Gallery Name: <input type="text" name="gname" value="<?php echo $row['Gallery_Name']; ?>"  /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Gallery Info" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remember input data in the forms even after refresh page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014146/how-to-remember-input-data-in-the-forms-even-after-refresh-page)

Comment: @larsAnders, nope, I am not using SESSIONS and don't intend to.

Comment: So, the form at the bottom - is that actually in a foreach loop and we're not seeing that part of the code?  Where is `$row['Gallery_Id']` coming from?

Comment: @larsAnders, added the code where the `$row` comes from

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Thanks for that @tadman. What I don't understand is, why string interpolation or concat is still allowed in PHP. Then, if someone uses PHP and SQL, it will be in an environment where it's not vulnerable to attacks. Why is it that I have to learn it this way? I most certainly did NOT learn this at uni

Comment: Sadly they don't teach the proper way in most university courses, so you're left with guides like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to set the record straight. String interpolation and concatenation are very useful, but when dealing with arbitrary user data you need to be extra careful about how you handle it. This goes for SQL and HTML alike.

Comment: So I tried sanitizing my code after your comment. And came up with an error. Can you please have a looksy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614469/like-statement-sanitization-sql-php

Answer (score 0):

You could print the html right after it's successfully inserted into the database:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    $gid = $_POST['gid'];
    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    $gtype = $_POST['gtype'];

    $update = " UPDATE galleries_info SET 
    Gallery_Name='$gname', Gallery_Type_Id='$gtype' WHERE Gallery_Id='$gid'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $update);
    //returns either false or object

    if(is_object($result2)){
    ?>
      <div class="updated_info_class">
       <h3>Gallery Info Updated!</h3>
       Gallery ID: <?php echo $gid; ?><br><br>
       Gallery Name: <?php echo $gname; ?><br><br>
       Gallery Type: <?php echo $gtype; ?><br><br>
     </div> 
    <?php
    } else {
        echo '<div class="warning">Ruh Roh! Not updated.</div>';
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```