# retain drop down selection after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have an HTML form with multiple drop down menu fields that get populated looping thru arrays for select data common between multiple fields.

```
<label>Techician:</label>
<select name="rcvTech" id="rcvTech">
    <option value="0">--Select Technician--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($tech as $t) {
            echo "<option value='$t'>$t</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

What could I do to have the selected data for all drop down menus retained when the form is submitted so that if there are any errors to correct the user would not have the tedious task of having to re-select each field over?

**Solution adapted from user5748817's post below:**

```
<label>Receiving techician:</label>
<select name="rcvTech" id="rcvTech">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">--Select Technician--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($tech as $t) {
            echo "<option value='$t'";
                if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['rcvTech'] == $t){
                    echo " selected";
                }
            echo ">$t</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014146/how-to-remember-input-data-in-the-forms-even-after-refresh-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to handle the multiple selected options you would need to collect the data as an array. So change the select name to rcvTech[]. When validating the data submitted, collect it in a session to be able to get the submitted values.

```
<label>Techician:</label>
<select name="rcvTech[]" id="rcvTech">
    <option value="0">--Select Technician--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($tech as $t) {
            if (in_array($t, $_SESSION['submitted'])) $selected=" selected";
            echo "<option value='".$t."' ".$selected.">".$t."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks user5748817, your suggested solution got me to where I wanted.