# Preselect files the user send last request

Tags: html, file, select

My user is completing a form where he has to upload files. Now something is wrong and I send the same page again and the user don't want to fill out the whole form again, so I enter the data send in the form automaticly. This is pretty easy with textboxes and select statements, but how do you do that with the file input?

Comment: I'm not sure if you just want the filename or its content. I guess you want the file's content. You could do this with some php as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: @Dixel I have a file input. My user has send invalid data. I don't want the user to select the files again, but instead have the the files shown again

Comment: You can either prevent the user to enter invalid input with html so that the input won't be sent utile it's valid. Or you can save the file using php session like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014146/how-to-remember-input-data-in-the-forms-even-after-refresh-page?rq=1).